# how to plot the tensorflow neural network object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried example code of tensorflow spiral dataset and constructed the neural network. I wanted to visualize the graphical structure of the network. 
PFB the code i tried.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    net = tflearn.input_data([None, 2])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,6,
                activation='tanh',weights_init='normal')
    print(net)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To visualize a graph, you should use TensorBoard. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) for how to use it.

You can add at the end of your code a summary writer, which will write an event file (containing the visualization of the graph) into the given location.

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    net = tflearn.input_data([None, 2])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,6,
                activation='tanh',weights_init='normal')

sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('tmp/tensorboard_log', sess.graph)
```

Then you just need to run `tensorboard --logdir tmp/tensorboard_log` and go in your browser to `localhost:6006/#graphs`.

Comment: "No graph definition files were found. " it throws this error instead

Comment: Do you have an event file in `tmp/tensorboard_log` ?

Comment: i now got the tensorboard_log and event file is exisiting. but the browser is not taking the event file.

Comment: "tf.Session(graph=graph)"  ..... here what should be the value passed to the graph attribute? should it be graph=tf.Graph() ?

Comment: Yes I created the graph at line 1

Comment: graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    net = tflearn.input_data([None, 2])
    net1 = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 6, activation='tanh',weights_init='normal')
    net2 = tflearn.fully_connected(net1, 3, activation='softmax')
    sgd = tflearn.SGD(learning_rate=0.3, lr_decay=0.96, decay_step=500)
    net3 = tflearn.regression(net2, optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    Y = to_categorical(y, 3)
    model = tflearn.DNN(net3)
  
    
    
    

sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('tmp/tensorboard_log', sess.graph)

Comment: this is the code after including the changes you prescribe .. still the graph is not generated in browser

Comment: Try to delete all event files in `tmp/tensorboard_log` and rerun the python script.